# How can I access the browser console on Opera Mobile on Android?

Tags: debug, opera-browser

How can I access the browser console on [Opera Mobile on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser)?

Browser console = something similar to the developer console window on Chrome, when pressing the keyboard shortcut Ctrl Shift J

Comment: Seems unlikely. It is a botched fork of Chromium. Most `chrome://urls` cannot be accessed. Even the official guide for remote debugging is outdated and no longer works.

Comment: Maybe some answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256331/is-it-possible-to-open-developer-tools-console-in-chrome-on-android-phone might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this app that I developed it may help you, 

[F12 | Browser Console for Mobile Devices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asfmapps.f12)

But if you are developing something and want to access Console for it, then following the steps in following link will be a better option
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Answer (score 2):

That feature seems to be unavailable for all major android browsers.
You could try Opera-mini instead.

1. Reset the console output by opening a new tab with the address debug:resetconsole
   [image: Reset output]
2. Open a tab on the page on which you want to do the inspection:
   [image: example.com]
3. Run JavaScript code on the page by replacing the address in the address bar with the following address `javascript:var%20n%3Ddocument.firstChild%3Bwhile%28n%20%26%26%20n.nodeType%21%3DNode.ELEMENT_NODE%29%20n%3Dn.nextSibling%3Bconsole.log%28n.outerHTML%29%3B`
4. Retrieve the output by opening a new tab with the address debug:console
   [image: Output]