# How to check Firefox/Chrome developer console/tools on Android without a computer?

Tags: chrome-for-android, xiaomi, firefox-for-android, debug

I am aware of these two questions

- [How can I access the browser console on Opera Mobile on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225798/216556)
- [Is it possible to open developer tools console in Chrome on Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256331/is-it-possible-to-open-developer-tools-console-in-chrome-on-android-phone)

However the first one is interested in Opera and that is not the browser I use for development.

As for the second one, there is some interesting answers, however my goal is to see the console only using a mobile Android device (Redmi Note 9S).

Comment: Sorry, I posted an app answer and deleted because I was told that app does not provide the console functionality.  [F12|Browser console for Android Devices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asfmapps.f12)  was the app

Answer (score 1):

That feature seems to be unavailable for all major android browsers.
You could try Opera-mini instead.

1. Reset the console output by opening a new tab with the address debug:resetconsole
   [image: Reset output]
2. Open a tab on the page on which you want to do the inspection:
   [image: example.com]
3. Run JavaScript code on the page by replacing the address in the address bar with the following address `javascript:var%20n%3Ddocument.firstChild%3Bwhile%28n%20%26%26%20n.nodeType%21%3DNode.ELEMENT_NODE%29%20n%3Dn.nextSibling%3Bconsole.log%28n.outerHTML%29%3B`
4. Retrieve the output by opening a new tab with the address debug:console
   [image: Output]